# не получается установить библиотеку python

Tags: python, python-3.x, library

пытался установить библиотеку Pyaudio, вот такая ошибка:

```
/storage/emulated/0 $ pip install PyAudio
Collecting PyAudio
Using cached PyAudio-0.2.11.tar.gz (37 kB)
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for PyAudio, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: PyAudio
Running setup.py install for PyAudio ... error
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
command: /data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/bin/python3.6 -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/cache/pip-install-7rnxyjsv/pyaudio_ba30e7632d07461c8006d23d45a9a130/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/cache/pip-install-7rnxyjsv/pyaudio_ba30e7632d07461c8006d23d45a9a130/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/cache/pip-record-_iehypyk/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/include/python3.6m/PyAudio
         cwd: /data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/cache/pip-install-7rnxyjsv/pyaudio_ba30e7632d07461c8006d23d45a9a130/
    Complete output (16 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-armv8l-3.6
    copying src/pyaudio.py -> build/lib.linux-armv8l-3.6
    running build_ext
    building '_portaudio' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.6
    creating build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.6/src
    arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Os -s -I/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/include/python3.6m -c src/_portaudiomodule.c -o build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.6/src/_portaudiomodule.o
    src/_portaudiomodule.c:29:10: fatal error: portaudio.h: No such file or directory
     #include "portaudio.h"
              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'arm-linux-androideabi-gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/bin/python3.6 -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/cache/pip-install-7rnxyjsv/pyaudio_ba30e7632d07461c8006d23d45a9a130/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/cache/pip-install-7rnxyjsv/pyaudio_ba30e7632d07461c8006d23d45a9a130/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/cache/pip-record-_iehypyk/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/include/python3.6m/PyAudio Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Вы явно запускаете установку в нестандартном окружении, а значит вам нужно скомпилировать PyAudio самостоятельно, а значит вам нужно установить все дополнительные заголовочные файлы вроде PortAudio, о чём вам и говорит текст этой ошибки

Comment: Скорее всего PyAudio не поддерживается вашей версией питона.
Проверить можно с помощью python --version. Затем установите нужный пакет [отсюда](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio)

Comment: план б. попробуйте https://python-poetry.org/

Comment: я устанавливаю на андроид, приложение pydroid

Comment: спасибо за ответ, сейчас попробую

Comment: эхх ничего не получается